# Strange behaviour of UpSet

Tags: upvalues, built-in-symbols

Can anyone explain what is going on here? I want to modify [`TensorRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorRank.html) for [`IdentityMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix.html), but it fails on its first attempt:

```
Unprotect[IdentityMatrix];
Attributes[IdentityMatrix]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[_]] ^= 2;
```

> *UpSet::write: Tag IdentityMatrix in TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[_]] is Protected. >>*

```
Attributes[IdentityMatrix]
```

> ```
> {Protected}
> ```

Huh?

Unprotecting it for the second time does work however:

```
Unprotect[IdentityMatrix];
TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[_]] ^= 2;
TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[n]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

This is on 9.0.1 for OS X, and I'm seeing the same behaviour on the cloud (version 10 for Linux).

Comment: It works fine for me in **V10**, **Windows 8.1**

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce this under V10 on Linux

Comment: Confirmed in **v9.0.1, Windows Vista 32bit**.

Comment: This is starting to look like a bug. Can anyone else confirm that the first attempt forks for V10 on Windows?

Comment: I don't see this under V8 btw.

Comment: @sebhofer That makes sense, because `TensorRank` was introduced in V9.

Comment: @TeakeNutma Lol, sorry for that :)

Comment: In Mathematica 10+, `TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[n]]` returns 2, so there is no need to modify TensorRank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Added*: Virtually the same issue came up on StackOverflow a few years ago: [Why do I have to evaluate this twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649379/why-do-i-have-to-evaluate-this-twice)]

I would not consider it a bug if the manipulation of `` System` `` variables do no go the way you want. It turns out that the definition of `TensorRank` is not loaded until it is first evaluated.  That initialization process resets the attributes of `IdentityMatrix`.

```
Quit[]

ClearAttributes[TensorRank, ReadProtected]

?? TensorRank
```

> TensorRank[tensor] gives the rank of tensor. >>

```
(*
  Attributes[TensorRank] = {Protected}

  TensorRank := System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[TensorRank],
   Hold[Grad,...,SymmetrizedArray],SymbolicTensors`SymbolicTensors`] /; System`Dump`TestLoad
*)
```

The initial definition shows that the actual definition is auto-loaded when `TensorRank` is evaluated.

For what it's worth, you can `UpSet` the value of `TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[_]]` in one go by evaluating `TensorRank` first.  In general, therefore, for similar sorts of redefinition of `` System` `` symbols, the symbols should be evaluated first.

```
TensorRank;
IdentityMatrix; (* unnecessary, but following my own advice above *)
Unprotect[IdentityMatrix];
Attributes[IdentityMatrix]
(*
  {}
*)

TensorRank[IdentityMatrix[_]] ^= 2;
(* no messages *)

TensorRank[IdentityMatrix["foo"]]
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It still looks like a bug to me though: why would the autoloading of `TensorRank` reset properties of `IdentityMatrix`?

Comment: @TeakeNutma Something like: `Unprotect[IdentityMatrix]; (* make some new definitions *); Protect[IdentityMatrix]`.  The code seems to be in a `.mx` file, so I can't say specifically.  I doubt the code would check the attributes and then reset them to what they were.  Since `IdentityMatrix` is in fact a tensor, it is not surprising to me that the symbolic tensor code fiddles with it.  (Evaluating `TensorRank` loads all the symbolic tensor code; the same thing happens if you evaluate `TensorProduct` or another such function.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 it looks like this is a bug. check the documentation example http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAttributes.html it is working fin from the first run before loading Log. I have faced same issue with Plus and Times.

Comment: @Algohi I think it is a conscious, intentional decision. But that is my personal opinion and we don't have to agree.  The `Log` example is not strictly equivalent.  `TensorRank` loaded a package that reset the attributes on `IdentityMatrix`; other functions may also reset attributes.  The documentation does not guarantee that once an attribute is changed, it won't be changed again. BTW, another ref. is http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModifyingBuiltInFunctions.html.